# “Convert” Option[x] to x

Tags: scala, casting, playframework, type-conversion

I working with play for Scala (2.1) and I need to convert an `Option[Long]` value to `Long`.

I know how to do the opposite, I mean:

```scala
def toOption[Long](value: Long): Option[Long] = if (value == null) None else Some(value)
```

But in my case, I have to pass a value of `Option[Long]` as a type into a method that takes `Long`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all, your implementation of "the opposite" has some serious problems. By putting a type parameter named `Long` on the method you're shadowing the `Long` type from the standard library. You probably mean the following instead:

```
def toOption(value: Long): Option[Long] =
  if (value == null) None else Some(value)
```

Even this is kind of nonsensical (since `scala.Long` is not a reference type and can never be `null`), unless you're referring to `java.lang.Long`, which is a recipe for pain and confusion. Finally, even if you were dealing with a reference type (like `String`), you'd be better off writing the following, which is exactly equivalent:

```
def toOption(value: String): Option[String] = Option(value)
```

This method will return `None` if and only if `value` is `null`.

To address your question, suppose we have the following method:

```
def foo(x: Long) = x * 2
```

You shouldn't generally think in terms of passing an `Option[Long]` to `foo`, but rather of "lifting" `foo` into the `Option` via `map`:

```
scala> val x: Option[Long] = Some(100L)
x: Option[Long] = Some(100)

scala> x map foo
res14: Option[Long] = Some(200)
```

The whole point of `Option` is to model (at the type level) the possibility of a "null" value in order to avoid a whole class of `NullPointerException`-y problems. Using `map` on the `Option` allows you to perform computations on the value that may be in the `Option` while continuing to model the possibility that it's empty.

As another answer notes, it's also possible to use `getOrElse` to "bail out" of the `Option`, but this usually isn't the idiomatic approach in Scala (except in cases where there really is a reasonable default value).

Comment: What if it’s an implementation req that we req long, is getOrElse the only approach?

Answer (score 66):

If you have x as Option[Long], `x.get` will give you Long.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If x is `None` (which is a possible value of `Option[Long]`), calling `get` will throw an error.

Comment: We can use x.getOrElse(None)

Comment: Yes the better option for this is using x.getOrElse()

Comment: How is this has more upvotes than accepted answer, what the hell? This answer is so harmful. One may see https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#210-must-not-use-optionget for details. I'd suggest to just delete this answer straightaway.

Answer (score 11):

This method is already defined on Option[A] and is called **get** :

```
scala> val x = Some(99L)
x: Some[Long] = Some(99)

scala> x.get
res0: Long = 99
```

The problem is that calling get on None will throw a NoSucheElement Exception:

```
scala> None.get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

thus you will not gain any benefits from using an Option type.

Thus as stated before you can use **getOrElse** if you can provide a sensible default value or handle the Exception.

The idiomatic scala way would be using map or a for-comprehension

```
x map (_ + 1)
res2: Option[Long] = Some(100)
```

or

```
for (i <- x) yield i +1
res3: Option[Long] = Some(100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Option is way to localise side-effect (your function can return empty value). And good style to lift your computation to Option (Option is Monad with ***map*** & ***flatMap*** methods).

```
val x = Option[Long](10) 
x.map { a => a + 10 }
```

And extract value with manually processing of side effect:

```
val res = x match {
  case Some(a) => s"Value: $a"
  case None    => "no value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what happens when the option is `None`. Do you provide a default value?

```
def unroll(opt: Option[Long]): Long = opt getOrElse -1L  // -1 if undefined

unroll(None) // -> -1
```

You could also throw an exception:

```
def unroll(opt: Option[Long]): Long = opt.getOrElse(throw 
  new IllegalArgumentException("The option is expected to be defined at this point")
)

unroll(None) // -> exception
```

In case, refrain from using `null`, unless you have very good reasons to use it (`opt.orNull`).

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned getOrElse is probably what you're looking for in answering your question directly.

Please note also that to convert to an option you can simply:

```
val myOption = Option(1)
```

myOption will now be Some(1)

```
val myOption = Option(null)
```

myOption will now be None.