# converting to lowercase a username before info goes to controller

Tags: scala, playframework

The login page of my app uses scala forms and something like:

```
@(myForm: Form[User])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit) {    
      @helper.inputText(myForm("username"))    
      @helper.inputPassword(myForm("password"))
....
```

the problem I have if that our login system is uppercase/lowercase insensitive so I need to convert the username captured at:

```
 @helper.inputText(myForm("username"))
```

to lowercase before going to the Application.Submit method. I tried:

```
 @helper.inputText(myForm("username").toLowerCase)
```

but I get the error

```
 "value toLowerCase is not a member of play.api.data.Field"
```

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `myForm("username").value.toLowerCase`. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/data/Field.html

Comment: I am getting the error:  value toLowerCase is not a member of Option[String]

Comment: try `myForm("username").value.get.toLowerCase`. But it won't work if value is `None`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765713/convert-optionx-to-x-in-scala

Comment: Getting the error:  
type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: play.api.data.Field

Comment: can't help anymore. Never read scala or play framework before this question.

Comment: Do you have a success function? Where you construct an object from form data? If yes, maybe you can convert to lower case there. https://alvinalexander.com/scala/play-framework-data-entry-form-example

Comment: Seems that will be the only way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Create a var with the value, then convert the var to lowercase.

```
var inputText = @helper.inputText(myForm("username"))
inputText = inputText.toLowerCase
```

Comment: will the value of inputText go to the

    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit)

?

Comment: I think you would need to reapply the new lowerCase value to the form("username"), then submit...